# Can't make my Apache server on Ubuntu online

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm having some issues trying to set up my Apache server... I'll explain what I want to do and what's happening. First of all, sorry for my grammar - not my native language!

I'm using Windows, and the idea is to set up an Apache server at an Ubuntu VM (VirtualBox) so that I can access it using my IP from other computers (from Windows outside of the VM, for example). Well, on ubuntu, I install Apache and, as I have found out there, it should already be accesible by IP once it is by localhost. The problem is when typing localhost drives me to the default apache page while my IP doesn't, so... What should I do?

P.S: From Network settings at Virtualbox, I picked "Bridged adapter" (or something similar) which I think is the correct one. What do you think about? And thank you!

EDIT: Well, as I have found it's not because of my VM settings - I can use its local IP to access to the web server from several devices inside the same network. We have that the problem is the apache server configuration, so... What do you think about?

Comment: Ok, thanks to everybody who helped here. The issue was (I feel a bit idiot) I had to open the ports at the router config page (I thought I didn't have to, most of times they came opened by default). Additionally, as it was the first time I did this, I didn't undertand where the problem could be or what I was really doing. Today Apache and FTP properly working. Really, thanks to you for the help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing "bridged adapter" is correct, if your "outside" network allows this (allows to request another IP on the "outside" network for use in the VM, which is then in the same network as the host that you use to run the VM.
If this is not possible, you have to use NAT networking, which will force you to do port forwarding into the VM which is a lot trickier, especially when you want to run a webserver.

Now where is your problem now? when you say is is accessible by localhost, are you trying this inside the VM, from a browser running inside the VM or from wget/curl?

---

More details now:

### your apache config

from your comment, it appears that your problem is not in the VM/Network config, but in the httpd.conf of your webserver.
the virtual host setting, to be precise.
can you quote the settings you have?  if you have an older linux/apache combo, these might be under /etc/httpd/httpd.conf, if you have more recent versions, you will find them probably under /etc/apache2/conf-available

we need to take a close look at the Listen, ServerName and ServerAlias directives.

Comment: Yeah, the first paragraph is correct; bridged adapter is the right one.

My problem then is, when I start the Apache server inside the VM, it is only accesible by searching localhost INSIDE the VM, not from Windows. I need it to be accesible from my public IP (the one you can find at whatismyip.com, for example) and from other computers, of course. Stuck on there...

Comment: please see edits above, - we need to look at your apache config!

Comment: Well, as I have recently installed both, VM and Apache, both are on their latest version so Apache is not using httpd.conf.

Next, about the config files, as I haven't still changed anything they must be on their defaults.I have read something like I had to add something to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf/. These are the problems when you're still a newbie with these things T-T

Comment: well I do not know what the defaults that you say are in your config are.

you need to tell me at least what your "Listen" directive says. From your symptoms, I would assume that it shows your loopback IP, 127.0.0.1, but you need show me what it says specifically.

Comment: Ok, in ports.conf there's a Listen 80 sentence which I think is what you're talking about. Any aditional info you can need, if you can tell me where to get it... As I say, I'm a bit new to this. If you need me to copy any file or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure port forwarding for the Virtualbox. Go to the VM settings in the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager / Page ‘Network’.

Comment: change from bridged to NAT

Comment: then change the port forwarding address to point to your desired port eg. 8080. If your webserver is running (in ubuntu) on windows open the web browser go to http://(ip of ubuntu):8080/

Comment: well, the problem here is I don't really know on which ports it runs on - I think they are 80 and 443. I'll try setting the adapter to NAT and aplying those rules...

Comment: change the ports inside ubuntu apache to listen to port 8080